# Solving a simple SQL problem to determine the Total earning of an event

Tags: sql

I have this SQL code, I run it but it doesn't give me the disired output.
For every current event Name.

if any future event name appears in the previous event name, record the price for the event names.

for example:

3/9/2023 has event name of classical concert but no previous event.
the total earning result will be zero.
since it also has even same day, the corresponding total earning will be zero.

07/09/2023 has event name classical concert.
if we check through all the previous event and the future event, only jazz festival has previous event which also has future event.
therefore, the total earning will be 60.
same as same day date.

12/09/2023 has event name of jazz festival, and only theater play occurs both in future and previous event. therefore, the total earning will be 40
same scenario for all event date.

For the last event date, since we don't have any event date that happens at the future, the value will result to zero.

```
WITH EventEarnings AS (
    SELECT
        e1.Event_Date AS "Event Date", e1.Event_Name AS "Event Name", e1.Price AS "Price",
        CASE
            WHEN e2.Event_Date > e1.Event_Date AND e2.Transaction_Date <= e1.Event_Date THEN e2.Price ELSE 0
        END AS "Earnings"
    FROM  [event].[dbo].[events] e1
    JOIN        [event].[dbo].[events] e2 ON e1.Event_Date <= e2.Event_Date
)
SELECT
    "Event Date",
    "Event Name",
    "Price",
    SUM("Earnings") AS "Total Earnings"
FROM
    EventEarnings
GROUP BY  "Event Date", "Event Name", "Price"
ORDER BY
    "Event Date";
```

My table structure :

- Event Date
- Transaction Date
- Event Name ac
- Price

Here is the expected output:

```
Expected Result
$0
$0
$60
$60
$40
$40
$40
$40
$0
$0
```

Here is my output :

```
Event Date  Event Name          Price   Total Eamings
03/09/2023  Classical Concert   70      370
03/09/2023  Jazz Festival       60      370
07/09/2023  Classical Concert   70      260
07/09/2023  Theater Play        40      260
12/09/2023  Jazz Festival       60      150
12/09/2023  Rock Concert        50      150
18/09/2023  Comedy Night        30      70
18/09/2023  Rock Concert        50      70
22/09/2023  Comedy Night        30      0
22/09/2023  Theater Play        40      0
```

Comment: Please tah your RDBMS

Comment: How do you want to achive your expected output ? what are the rules behind ?

Comment: For every current event Name.

if any future event name appears in the previous event name, record the price for the event names.

for example:

Comment: 3/9/2023 has event name of classical concert but no previous event. 
the total earning result will be zero.
since it also has even same day, the corresponding total earning will be zero.

07/09/2023 has event name classical concert. 
if we check through all the previous event and the future event, only jazz festival has previous event which also has future event.
therefore, the total earning will be 60.
same as same day date. 

12/09/2023 has event name  jazz festival, and only theater play occurs in future and previous events. therefore, the total earnings will be 40

Comment: Can you update your question with the details you provided. Help us to help you :)

Comment: Yea, I have done that

Answer (score 0):

Try the following :

```
WITH EventEarnings AS (
    SELECT
        e1.Event_Date AS "Event Date",
        e1.Event_Name AS "Event Name",
        e1.Price AS "Price",
        CASE
            WHEN e2.Event_Date > e1.Event_Date THEN e2.Price ELSE 0
        END AS "Earnings"
    FROM  [event].[dbo].[events] e1
    JOIN  [event].[dbo].[events] e2 ON e1.Event_Date <= e2.Event_Date
)
SELECT
    "Event Date",
    "Event Name",
    "Price",
    SUM("Earnings") AS "Total Earnings"
FROM
    EventEarnings
GROUP BY  "Event Date", "Event Name", "Price"
ORDER BY  "Event Date";
```

Comment: It's not giving the desired Result above... 
Expected Result
$0 
$0 
$60 
$60 
$40 
$40 
$40 
$40 
$0 
$0 
That is the desired result

Comment: You mentioned two outputs. Also what is the input ? your tables structures?

Comment: The expected result is the output I needed to generate.

Comment: The table structure are: Event Date  Transaction Date Event Name  Price.

My output is the Total earnings.

Expected output is the Expected result

Comment: The question is unclear. Please provide some sample input and desired output explanation with an example